# Read-only binding and one-way converters using JGoodies binding

Tags: java, binding, converters, jgoodies

I am attempting to use JGoodies Binding 2.9.1 to bind the `enabled` property of a `JTextField` to an enum property. I want this to be a one-way operation: when the property changes, I want the `JTextField` to become enabled or disabled, but I never want to go the other way and set the enum property based on the `enabled` value.

Although I think I set up everything properly, I am getting a *PropertyAccessException: Failed to set an adapted Java Bean property*.

My model is a standard Java Bean with property change events:

```
public static String MY_PROPERTY = "myProperty";
private MyEnum myProperty;

public MyEnum getMyProperty() { return myProperty; }

public void setMyProperty(final MyEnum newValue) {
    final MyEnum oldValue = myProperty;
    if (newValue == oldValue) { return; }
    myProperty = newValue;
    changeSupport.firePropertyChange(MY_PROPERTY, oldValue, newValue);
}
```

In my view I have a one-way converter that will return true when the bound value matches the provided value:

```
private final class EnumMatchToEnabledConverter implements BindingConverter<MyEnum, Boolean> {
    private MyEnum match;

    public EnumMatchToEnabledConverter (MyEnum match) {
        this.match = match;
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean targetValue(MyEnum source) {
        return (source == match);
    }

    @Override
    public MyEnum sourceValue(Boolean target) {
        // this wouldn't make sense
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

Then I set up the binding:

```
PresentationModel<MyModel> pm = new PresentationModel<MyModel>(model);
Bindings.bind(
    myTextField, "enabled", new ConverterValueModel(
        pm.getModel(MyModel.MY_PROPERTY),
        new EnumMatchToEnabledConverter(MyEnum.MyValue)));
```

To my surprise, `EnumMatchToEnabledConverter`'s `sourceValue()` method gets called, and because it raises an `UnsupportedOperationException` I get a `PropertyAccessException` from the binding.

I also tried explicitly telling the binding not to use the setter, but I still got the same behavior:

```
Bindings.bind(
    myTextField, "enabled", new ConverterValueModel(
        pm.getModel(MyModel.MY_PROPERTY, "getMyProperty", null), // null setter!
        new EnumMatchToEnabledConverter(MyEnum.MyValue)));
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Someone else appears to have been successful doing this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948147/how-can-i-bind-a-property-e-g-an-enum-to-a-component-property-of-a-different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround. It's ugly, but it works.

I wrap my `ConverterValueModel` with a `BufferedValueModel` whose `ValueModel` trigger never triggers.

```
Bindings.bind(
    myTextField,
    "enabled",
    new BufferedValueModel(
        new ConverterValueModel(
            pm.getModel(MyModel.MY_PROPERTY),
            new EnumMatchToEnabledConverter(MyEnum.MyValue)),
        new AbstractValueModel() {
            @Override public Object getValue() { return null; }
            @Override public void setValue(Object o) {}
        }));
```